# Building Docker container for .NET Framework 4.7.x in Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, docker, azure-devops, .net-4.0

I currently have a standard .NET Framework web application. With Docker support. I would like to build these Docker images using Azure DevOps but there don't seem to be any clear tutorials on how to do that.

I can build the Docker image using the build button in Visual Studio. This makes a usable image that works. Though I know how to either select such a build option in Azure DevOps or generally outside Visual Studio.

What I'm using: .NET Framework 4.7.2 boilerplate web app with Docker support.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with a general `Build, test, and push Docker container apps` set of tasks.

When you create a build you can choose a template for the build, you'd need to use the docker build template. Otherwise just follow the linked tutorial.

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker?view=azure-devops

Comment: I've tried doing this, but the build output of a normal production build vs a Docker production build seems to export different files.